# Установка Apche HttpClient в Intellij Idea

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, понадобился Apache HttpClient. Скачал с оф. сайта последнюю версию binary. Пытался добавить в глобальные библиотеки сначала сам архив, потом только папку `lib` из него. В первом случае библиотека вообще не добавляется, во втором добавляется, но есть такая проблема. Сам класс `HttpClient` является абстрактным. Либо я чего то не понимаю, либо что-то делаю не так, ибо по уроками примерам такого нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне сделать или какую именно версию скачать(сейчас 4.5.2), чтобы `HttpClient` не не надо было писать с нуля, либо его по любому писать с 0?

Comment: А можете показать или дать ссылку на код из этого урока, где создается объект этого класса.

Comment: @Riĥard Brugekĥaim , [ссылка](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html), в самом низу страницы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Та документация безбожно устарела. Вот [инструкция](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/), которая вам нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно, но все равно не работает. Использовал [этот код](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html), точнее из первого пункта. Теперь `CloseableHttpClient is abstract`

Comment: Так там не нужно самому создавать объект. Он генерируется кодом HttpClients.createDefault();

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное)